# What is 给 doing in 你给宠坏了 and 一个人给丢在家里 (Matilda 玛蒂尔达, p.7)?

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context

I bought the Chinese version of Matilda, and I'm confused about this:

[image: Matilda, page 7]

Specifically, I'm confused about why [给](http://dict.cn/%E7%BB%99) (usually meaning "to give") is in these phrases:

> 你给宠坏了
> You're getting spoiled  [original English ([ref.](http://jssisdubai.com/document/uploaded/matilda.pdf))]
> You give spoiled  [literal translation]
>
> 一个人给丢在家里
> left alone in the house  [original English]
> a person give lost in the house  [literal translation]

The use of 给 as "to give" makes no sense to me; perhaps 给 has an additional meaning I'm unaware of.

**Question**: What is 给 doing in 你给宠坏了 and 一个人给丢在家里?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two phrases sound a bit stilted. When 给 is used as the sense of 被, it's better you add the one who performs that action. For example, 你给他宠坏了, 你给他教坏了 and etc.

玛蒂尔达几乎天天一个人给丢在家里 is not a very good sentence in my opinion. It might be ok colloquially, but it's not good in writing. 玛蒂尔达几乎天天被一个人丢在家里 is probably an improvement.

Comment: Seems more common in Beijing Dialect

Answer (score 2):

「給」here is a colloquial, alternative way of expressing the same meaning as「被」. It is non-standard in Standard Chinese.

[image]